# Trying document.getElementById and add.EventListener to shutdown a RPi

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, raspberry-pi

it is my first question in stackoverflow and my first code in HTML/JS. I'm using NodeJS, bootstrap, express and ejs.

I'm trying to shutdown a Raspberry PI from the navigation bar. The code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Foot.io</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"> 
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/Rules">Rules</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/System">System</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fas fa-power-off"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="Reboot" href="#">Reboot</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="Shutdown" href="#">Shutdown</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the script tag is:

```
  <script>
 document.getElementById("Reboot").addEventListener("click", function(){console.log("rebooting...");});
 document.getElementById("Shutdown").addEventListener("click", function(){console.log("shuting down...");});</script>
```

All of this code is included in a partial called "navigation.ejs"

I also try making a blank HTML with a simple button and it doesn't works.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't works"? Can you explain the behaviour? Is there an error?

Comment: I mean nothing happens. There is no errors. Would I need some required module?

Comment: Sorry guys, it's working through the client console, it's a conceptual error. And a syntax error in the try button... Newbie stuff...